# Packets are not filtering by the program i created using scapy module in python

Tags: scapy, packet-sniffers

I started learning ethical hacking few days ago. I have reached the topic "packet sniffer". I created a very basic program using python, but I am not able to see my own network-filtered packet information after running the code in a Kali terminal. This is my code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http

def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface= interface, store= False, prn= process_sniffed_packet)


def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        print(packet)

sniff("eth0")
```

Comment: If you run `tcpdump -i eth0`, do you see traffic? The other thing to check is if you take out the conditional to check for HTTP request, does it still print packets?

Comment: Yes, I  see a traffic whenever i browse. And if i take out the check condition HTTP request it doesn't print anything in terminal window

Comment: "Yes, I see a traffic whenever i browse." => this doesn't make any sense. Can you expand or add more context?

Comment: after running the command it showed=>**tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes** thats it

Comment: Can you run `tcpdump -D` and post the results *in your question*? There's an edit button below your question.

Comment: 1.eth0 [Up, Running]
2.lo [Up, Running, Loopback]
3.any (Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces) [Up, Running]
4.nflog (Linux netfilter log (NFLOG) interface) [none]
5.nfqueue (Linux netfilter queue (NFQUEUE) interface) [none]
root@kali:~#

Comment: Your code works just fine. Go to a HTTP page. If it's HTTPS it will not work and check your interface with ifconfig if its really eth0.